# Vimrc syntax move up and down a certain line continously

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript, movement

So I am new to Vim and I am trying to understand the language of `vimrc`. I have this in my `vimrc`:

```
map <F8> <C-E>: sleep 100m<CR>j<F8>
```

This would automatically move the cursor down when I press `F8`.  However, what if I want the cursor to move down 1 line then move up 1 line, then down 1 line again and repeat? 
It's a dumb question I know, but I try to understand how the language vimscript works. Anyway, I try this:

```
map <F8> <C-E>: sleep 100m<CR>1j1k<F8>
```

That only scolls downward, not upward.  I want it to move down 1 line, then up 1 line then repeat until I press `Ctrl-C` to cancel.

Pleast let me know your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to include the whole sequence, including the opposite of `<C-E>`, which is `<C-Y>`, and also the `:sleep`.

```
map <F8> <C-E>:sleep 100m<CR>j<C-Y>:sleep 100m<CR>k<F8>
```